# I am not able to create a new ionic project due to some error

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to create new project in Ionic 6 since the new upgrade in ionic 7 has some concepts that I am not aware of (Standalones). I am quite new to the latest angular upgrades. Therefore I want to stick with Ionic 6.

This is my step-by-step workflow.\

I switched to node 16 using `nvm use 16`

The version now is node v16.20.0 (npm v8.19.4)

I uninstalled the ionic/cli and Installed it again using

```
npm i npm install -g @ionic/cli@6
```

My ionic version is `6.20.9`

[image]

Now when I try to create a new ionic project then I am ending upon the error as shown below.

[image]

What is the issue here? Please help.

Comment: Please provide more of the error message. You've cut off the (probably) useful bit.

Comment: The error looks like this. Please refer updated image.

Comment: "Can't find Python executable". Looks like you need to install Python.

Comment: > Now when I try to create a new ionic project then I am ending upon the error as shown below.

Which command are you using for this?

Comment: I am creating a new project in ionic.

ionic start <app name> tabs --type=ionic-angular --capacitor

Answer (score 0):

> I switched to node 16 using nvm use 16

I suspect your app has legacy dependencies that do not work with node 16.

`python2` was required for older versions of `sass`. It looks like a dependency/node-npm mismatch issue, possibly unrelated to Ionic. You can confirm this by installing dependencies, i.e. `npm install` on the project folder, which should produce the same error in that case.

For a workaround, You can try to initialize ionic in a new directory or update the existing dependencies & try again.